# Xcode 6.0 iOS 8 KeyboardTypeNumberPad button not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am building my app with xcode 6 ios 8.0. I have a UITextField with keyboardType UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad and added a done button to the keyboard but they didn't work in ios 8.0 xcode 6.0 . Its all working fine till the latest version ios 7.1.2 release.

I subscribe to the keyboard showing notification and showing button on below method call.

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note

Also , i'm getting the below log:-  I didn't got any log till the ios 7.1.2

Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default ios 8.0

Anyone facing this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of my own problem.

Below is the code which will work for iOS 8.0 and also for below versions.

I have tested it on iOS 7 and 8.0 (Xcode Version 6.0.1)

```
UIWindow* tempWindow;

UIView* keyboard;

for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
{
   if ([NSStringFromClass([window class]) isEqualToString:@"UITextEffectsWindow"])
    {
        tempWindow = window;
         break;
      }
    }

for(int i = 0 ; i < [tempWindow.subviews count] ; i++)
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    // keyboard found, add the button

       if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES){
            [keyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];
        }
        //This code will work on iOS 8.0
        else if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES){

            for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboard.subviews count] ; i++)
            {
                UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

                if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES){
                    [hostkeyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];
                }
            }                
        }
}
```

But , I still getting this warning:-

Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Ignorning this warning i got it working.

Hope this help anyone.